# error while updating Android SDK

Tags: android, linux, eclipse, sdk

Hi I am trying to update SDK manager but I am getting the following error:
Please anyone if can help me. I am working on Ubuntu 12.04 and android version 4.4.2. Thanks in advance

```
Downloading Android SDK Tools, revision 24.0.2
URL not found: /home/archana/Downloads/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20140702/sdk/temp/tools_r24.0.2-linux.zip (Permission denied)
Downloading Android SDK Platform-tools, revision 21
URL not found: /home/archana/Downloads/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20140702/sdk/temp/platform-tools_r21-linux.zip (Permission denied)
Downloading Documentation for Android SDK, API 21, revision 1
URL not found: /home/archana/Downloads/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20140702/sdk/temp/docs-21_r01.zip (Permission denied)
Downloading SDK Platform Android 5.0.1, API 21, revision 2
```

Comment: can u please check what permissions r u having for your Downloads folder? otherwise just change the permissions `sudo chmod -R 777 ~/Downloads`

Comment: http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/migrate.html

Answer (score 0):

I just installed android studio today and was having the same problem the only difference is that I run windows
    URL not found: /home/archana/Downloads/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20140702/sdk/temp/docs-            21_r01.zip (Access denied)
The solution in windows is very simple, all I'd to do was run the SDK manager as Administrator and then selected waht I needed to install and it worked. So I'd suggest you the same thing, run your SDK Manager as the root user.
Hope it helps.